# Using Webservice to call external Json file using ajax call

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, web-services, asmx

I have a Json file and an ajax call in Javascript file. Trying to write correct webservice method using Hello World asmx file template. What should I write in method in order to make it display/return/read json data on website?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:56537/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (Result) {
        debugger;
        Result = Result.d;
        var data = [];
var dataResource = response
```

Comment: You can still make an ASMX Web Service, but it really isn't supported much by Microsoft any more.  Better to go with a WCF Service application. You can use DataContractJsonSerilizer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats is the solution that worked for me:

[WebMethod]

```
public string HelloWorld() {

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\data.json"))
    {

        string json = r.ReadToEnd();

        return json;

    }
```